# Typescript adding methods with decorator type does not exist

Tags: typescript

I want to create a decorator that adds a method to a class.

```
export function Deco() {
  return function<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
    constructor.prototype.someMethod = function() {

    };
  };
}


@Deco()
class Test {

}
```

The problem is when I'm trying to invoke the added method, I am getting typescript error:

> Property someMethod does not exist on type Test.

```
const test = new Test();

test.someMethod();
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Presumably because you're not typing the return of the decorator to be `T & SomeMethodHaver` or whatever.

Comment: Can you add an example, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators can't influence the structure of the type. There is a simple workaround to this. Invoke the decorator with the class, and inside the function create a derived class with the methods you want. The result of the function will the new "decorated" class and it will have all the methods:

```
export function Deco() {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
        return class extends constructor {
            someMethod() {

            }
        }
    };
}


let Test = Deco()(class {
    // Other stuff
});

const test = new Test();
test.someMethod();
```

Comment: I am losing the cleaner syntax of decorators.

Comment: @undefined Yes you would, there is no other option unfortunately... for now anyway

Comment: Note that this may be allowed in the future. Also _not_ using decorator syntax has the advantage that you are not writing to a deprecated proposal that was never adopted. TypeScript will eventually implement the superseding proposal, rendering your code legacy. Angular users will have fun

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir but now, I can I use the Test method as a type of generic, it's not working.

Comment: @undefined what error are you getting? I tested the code with TS 2.7

Comment: export const Todo = Deco()(_Todo); cannot find name Todo

Comment: @undefined Works.. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20function%20Deco()%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20function%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%3E(constructor%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20class%20extends%20constructor%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09someMethod()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20_Todo%20%7B%0D%0A%09%2F%2F%20Other%20stuff%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20const%20Todo%20%3D%20Deco()(_Todo)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20Todo()%3B%0D%0Atest.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A

Comment: Maybe something with my IDE. Thanks!

Comment: @AluanHaddad what's the superseding proposal? Is it what Angular uses?