# Typescript decorator constructor overwriting including additional arguments

Tags: typescript, constructor, decorator

According to the [typescript decorators documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) the decorator example for replacing a constructor does not pass any arguments to the decorator function. How am I able to achieve this?

This is what the doc says

```js
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
  return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  }
}

@classDecorator
class Greeter {
  property = "property";
  hello: string;
  constructor(m: string) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
}
```

But I want now to pass arguments like using the decorator as follows

```js
@classDecorator({
  // some object properties fitting DecoratorData type
})
```

I simply tried to add a second data parameter

```js
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]): {}}>(constructor: T, data: DecoratorData)
```

But this just tslint *2 arguments required, got 1*. Inserting a `null` placeholder doesn't work either. Also I tried using the `constructor` parameter as a second optional parameter. This leads to a signature missmatch error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a decorator generator, a function which returns a decorator function. The generator function can take extra arguments, and the inner decorator function can capture those parameters and use them.

```
function classDecorator(data: DecoratorData) {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
        return class extends constructor {
            newProperty = "new property";
            hello = "override";
            // use daat here 
        }
    }
}

@classDecorator({ data: "" })
class Greeter {
    property = "property";
    hello: string;
    constructor(m: string) {
        this.hello = m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! The properties are overwritten very well. Am I able to access the new constructor attributes like <code>newProperty</code> in the default constructor?

Comment: @ngfelixl from inside the class I don't know of a way to do this (except declare the field in `Greeter` and have is set by the decorator). For access from the outside, you can't use decorators, they can't affect the structure of the class, but you can use a regular function, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599889/typescript-adding-methods-with-decorator-type-does-not-exist/48599986#48599986